# Xcode 7 playground is always in the running and does not show the result，how to fix it ？

Tags: swift-playground, xcode7-beta4

In Xcode 7 beta4, when I write the swift playground, it is always in the running and does not show the result. It seems to stop in the running.
What happened?

Comment: [the progress hub of the running is still running](http://7xk0ki.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/15-8-17/68649060.jpg)

Comment: when I open the Xcode, It pops up the [window](http://7xk0ki.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/15-8-17/13425416.jpg) saying "SpringBoard quit unexpectedly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the Xcode to the new version to solve the problem